# Failed to start virtual machine - Azure Portal Error

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine

The virtual machine was working fine before I stopped it on Friday, when I tried to start it today it gives me below error and failed to start -

`Failed to start the virtual machine 'MEANSERVER'. The operation 'dbfed9674f14acc2918a07348699bfbd' failed: 'Cannot perform the operation on a stopped deployment.'`

I have no idea what so ever went wrong. Request help for same.

Comment: Do you create the VM with your VHD or market?

Comment: No i created it from linux server available from microsoft azure

Comment: Your VM is classic VM or ARM mode VM?

Comment: It is classic VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your error, it seems that you shutdown your VM but Azure does not deallocate them. You could try to use the steps below:

1.Restart your VM on new [Azure Portal](http://portal.azure.com).

2.Resize your VM. When you resize your VM, your VM will run in a new host.

3.If they does not work, you could delete your VM(keep disk) and use the VHD to create a new VM. You could refer this [link](https://www.petri.com/recreate-virtual-machine-in-microsoft-azure).